# Javascript working offline, but not when uploaded to website

Tags: php, javascript, web

Im helping out a friend by making a website to help their shop. It works well when im running it on a webserver on my laptop. It loads the images just fine. But when I upload it to the site it doesnt work

Ive stripped out a lot of he code to just include whats important.

The website is http://www.adamwalker.net84.net/index.php

from what i can make out it might be in one of these 2 files... but im really not sure.... but these are the ones giving errors in the console

custom.js

```
    // Jquery with no conflict
   jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

//##########################################
// COLUMNIZR
//##########################################

$('.multicolumn').columnize({ 
    columns: 2
});


//##########################################
// CAROUSEL
//##########################################

$('#mycarousel').jcarousel({
    // Configuration goes here (http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/)
    vertical: false
});

$('#mycarousel-vertical').jcarousel({
    // Configuration goes here (http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/)
    vertical: true
});

//##########################################
// LOF SLIDER
//##########################################


var buttons = { previous:$('#home-slider .button-previous') ,
                    next:$('#home-slider .button-next') };  



$('#home-slider').lofJSidernews( {
    interval        : 4000,
    direction       : 'opacitys',   
    easing          : 'easeInOutExpo',
    duration        : 1200,
    auto            : true,
    maxItemDisplay  : 5,
    navPosition     : 'horizontal', // horizontal
    navigatorHeight : 73,
    navigatorWidth  : 188,
    mainWidth       : 940,
    buttons: buttons
});




//##########################################
// Superfish
//##########################################

$("ul.sf-menu").superfish({ 
    animation: {height:'show'},   // slide-down effect without fade-in 
    delay:     800 ,              // 1.2 second delay on mouseout 
    autoArrows:  false,
    speed: 100
});


//##########################################
// PROJECT SLIDER
//##########################################

$('.project-slider').flexslider({
    animation: "fade",
    controlNav: true,
    directionNav: false,
    keyboardNav: true
});


//##########################################
// Filter - Isotope 
//##########################################


var $container = $('#filter-container');

$container.imagesLoaded( function(){
    $container.isotope({
        itemSelector : 'figure',
        filter: '*',
        resizable: false,
        animationEngine: 'jquery'
    });
});

// filter buttons

$('#filter-buttons a').click(function(){

    // select current
    var $optionSet = $(this).parents('#filter-buttons');
    $optionSet.find('.selected').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');

    var selector = $(this).attr('data-filter');
    $container.isotope({ filter: selector });
    return false;
});

//##########################################
// Tool tips
//##########################################


$('.poshytip').poshytip({
    className: 'tip-twitter',
    showTimeout: 1,
    alignTo: 'target',
    alignX: 'center',
    offsetY: 5,
    allowTipHover: false
});



$('.form-poshytip').poshytip({
    className: 'tip-twitter',
    showOn: 'focus',
    alignTo: 'target',
    alignX: 'right',
    alignY: 'center',
    offsetX: 5
});

//##########################################
// Tweet feed
//##########################################

$("#tweets").tweet({
    count: 3,
    username: "ansimuz"
});

//##########################################
// PrettyPhoto
//##########################################

$('a[data-rel]').each(function() {
    $(this).attr('rel', $(this).data('rel'));
});

$("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto();


//##########################################
// Accordion box
//##########################################

$('.accordion-container').hide(); 
$('.accordion-trigger:first').addClass('active').next().show();
$('.accordion-trigger').click(function(){
    if( $(this).next().is(':hidden') ) { 
        $('.accordion-trigger').removeClass('active').next().slideUp();
        $(this).toggleClass('active').next().slideDown();
    }
    return false;
});

//##########################################
// Toggle box
//##########################################

$('.toggle-trigger').click(function() {
    $(this).next().toggle('slow');
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
    return false;
}).next().hide();




//##########################################
// Tabs
//##########################################

$(".tabs").tabs("div.panes > div", {effect: 'fade'});



//##########################################
// Create Combo Navi
//##########################################    

// Create the dropdown base
$("<select id='comboNav' />").appendTo("#combo-holder");

// Create default option "Go to..."
$("<option />", {
    "selected": "selected",
    "value"   : "",
    "text"    : "Navigation"
}).appendTo("#combo-holder select");

// Populate dropdown with menu items
$("#nav a").each(function() {
    var el = $(this);       
    var label = $(this).parent().parent().attr('id');
    var sub = (label == 'nav') ? '' : '- ';

    $("<option />", {
     "value"   : el.attr("href"),
     "text"    :  sub + el.text()
    }).appendTo("#combo-holder select");
});


//##########################################
// Combo Navigation action
//##########################################

$("#comboNav").change(function() {
  location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;
});


//##########################################
// Resize event
//##########################################

$(window).resize(function() {

    var w = $(window).width();
    //console.log(w);

    $container.isotope('reLayout');

}).trigger("resize");


    });//close
```

or jQuery FlexSlider v1.8

Comment: Links to other sites may become unavailable. Could you post the essential code here, on-site, please? That way your question will be useful for future visitors, even if the link goes down.

Comment: Press F12 on your browser to access the console. It'll tell you the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm noticing a few issues with your site.

First, it looks like your webhost loads their content and javascript into your page when there is a 404.  (I see javascript being requested from error404.000webhost.com).  That's quite bad practice.  I would immediately move to a new webhost (I know, sometimes easier said than done, but don't do business with companies that hijack your error pages... leads to weird problems - perhaps this one?!)

Second, the error is that $('.multicolumn') does not have a method called columnize().  I found this by using the web tools inspector in chrome.

Moving on to the network tab, I noticed javascript that appears to be used for the column building tool.  http://www.adamwalker.net84.net/js/jquery.columnizer.min.js  -- this is a 0-byte file (not a 404), so this is your problem.  This file is empty (or not being served for some reason), which causes the rest of your code to fail.

Comment: you are an absolute superstar, and i thankyou for that. The host is just a free one im using to check it all works in the browser etc. its purely for testing, they use a better one. I fixed it by reuploading the jquery.columnizer.min.js, and by removing columnize

Answer (score 0):

Couple of your Javascript files don't contain valid javascript code:

- jquery.easing.js
- jquery.flexslider.js

You have couple of empty files:

- jquery.columnizer.min.js
- css3-mediaqueries.js

Upload correct javascript files to your server.